# Receiving "None" during my program randomly?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def validateGuess():
    print(letters)
    inputGuess= input("Choose one of the letters above:")
    if len(inputGuess)> 1:
        inputGuess=input("Choose ONE of the letters above:")
return inputGuess

def wordLength():
    length=input("Welcome to Hangman. How many letters in the secret word?")
    length1=int(length)
    if length1 <0:
        length=input("Welcome to Hangman. How many letters in the secret word?")
    return length    

def guessAmount():
    guesses=input("How many guesses would you like?")
    guesses1=int(guesses)
    if guesses1 < 0:
         guesses=input("How many guesses would you like?")
    return guesses

welcome=wordLength()
remain=input("Do you want to print the count of how many words remain [Y/N]?")
guessNumber=int(guessAmount())
F=open('dictionary.txt')
F1=F.readlines()


welcome2=int(welcome)
a_list=[word.strip('\n') for word in F1]
possible_words = [x for x in a_list if len(x) == welcome2]

letters=      ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']
while guessNumber > 0:
    letter_guess=validateGuess()
    guessNumber -= 1
    letters=letters.remove(letter_guess)
```

Basically this is the beginning of an Evil Hangman game i'm creating, but I've come upon a problem I've never seen before. Whenever I run the program, whenever I get to the letter guess part of my while loop, I enter a letter, for instance b, and for some reason it reports back "None". I believe it has something to do with

```
letters=letters.remove(letter_guess)
```

but I'm not positive. I'm just trying to remove the user's letter guess from my list of letters each turn. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

[`list.remove()`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types) operates in-place. That is, it modifies the object it's called upon, it doesn't return a new list without the value.

In short, just use:

```
letters.remove(letter_guess)
```

Comment: Wow that was simple. Thanks a lot!